# Tarski number is not a quasi isometric invariant, an example?

Tags: gr.group-theory

I know that Tarski number is not a quasi isometric invariant, i.e.

Let $G,H$ be two groups such that $G\sim_{QI} H$, then it is not necessary to have $T(G)=T(H)$.

But can you bring an example for this statement?!

Comment: I presume you are referring to [the 2014 paper by Ershov, Golan, and Sapir](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.2202.pdf) for the existence of $G$ and $H$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, I think they have a remark about it, there.

Comment: The phrase before Theorem 1.3 in the paper cited above says that a concrete example can be found in [5]\ and [6]. Its Tarski number is estimated as well.

Comment: [5] M. Ershov, Kazhdan quotients of Golod-Shafarevich groups, with appendices by A. Jaikin-Zapirain,
Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) 102 (2011), no. 4, 599-636.
[6] M. Ershov and A. Jaikin-Zapirain, Groups of positive weighted deficiency, J. Reine Angew. Math.
677 (2013), no. 677, 71-134.

Comment: By the way, Theorem 1.3 in the paper of Ershov, Golan, and Sapir, (extracted from [5],[6]), explains that $T(H)-T(G)$ can be arbitrary large under the condition that $G$ and $H$ are quasi-isometric (even commensurated). Indeed they show that there is a f.g. group $G$ with a sequence of finite index subgroups $H_m<G$ for which $T(H_m)>m+2$.